# Using couchdb on NFS

Tags: couchdb, nfs

I am planning to use couchdb on a Linux VM with some limited local storage and a huge amount of NFS storage. What I would like to do is run one couchdb instance, but keep some databases on the local storage and some on the NFS.

-If the NFS goes down and the couchdb process enters the 'D' state, will I still be able to talk to couch over HTTP?
-Furthermore, will I still be able to access databases on the local VM storage?

As I asked in the question, the couchdb process could go into the 'D' state for prolonged periods of time if it is performing an I/O operation over NFS. This state is NOT interruptible in any way.

Does couchdb account for this situation? Is there a strategy for using multiple couch processes?

Answer (score 0):

To store some databases on the NFS mounted drive, just mount it as say 'test' in your storage location on your server and append 'test/' as a prefix to all databases that you want on your mounted storage instead of on your local.

If the NFS goes down you should still be able to extract the data from the databases that are stored on your local machine (if you mount it as described above).

CouchDB stores your databases as JSON-files on your HDD, so you can just access the database files and open them as long as you have access to the storage.

Comment: While this suggests a mechanism I can use to have DBs on different drives, you haven't really answered if couchdb will still respond if NFS goes down. Please see the edit to my question.